# How to run object detection on single image using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I am currently using the forked version of https://github.com/am15h/object_detection_flutter.git , which is https://github.com/TexMexMax/object_detection_flutter.git .

Can someone help me out in figuring out how to perform inference on single image chosen from gallery rather than real-time option provided.

PS: Sorry I am new to flutter.

Comment: check firebase object detection dependency.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/object-detection